# Table summarization in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have to do a program to summarize a table, for example:

```
Gender    Height
Female    120
Male      160
Female    180
```

and the result has to be the average, like this:

```
Female 150
Male 160
```

So far I got this:

```
altura :: [([Char], Integer)] -> Integer
altura [] = 1
altura ((gender,height ): x) = if gender == "Female"
then height + (altura x)
else if gender == "Male"
then height + (altura x)
else 0
```

How can I get the gender and the division?

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the summed height and count (population) for each gender separately as you go along the list, then, at the end of the list, divide the summed height by the count for each gender to get the average height for each gender:

```hs
import Data.Ratio  ((%))

averages :: [(String, Integer)] -> (Rational, Rational)
averages = go 0 0 0 0
  where
    rat :: Integer -> Integer -> Rational
    rat 0 0 = 0
    rat n d = n % d

    go :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [(String, Integer)] -> (Rational, Rational)
    go fHeight fCount mHeight mCount [] = (rat fHeight fCount, rat mHeight mCount)
    go fHeight fCount mHeight mCount (("Female", height):xs) = go (fHeight + height) (fCount + 1) mHeight mCount xs
    go fHeight fCount mHeight mCount (("Male",   height):xs) = go fHeight fCount (mHeight + height) (mCount + 1) xs
```

This gives:

```
> averages [("Female", 120), ("Male", 160), ("Female", 180)]
(150 % 1,160 % 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break down this problem into two parts:

- first grouping a list of pairs `[(a, b)]` into a list of pairs `[(a, [b])]` where all the `(a, b)` with the same `a` have been gathered together.
- then computing the average for each list of integers

This gives us:

```
module Averages where

import Data.Function
import Data.Ratio
import Data.List

classes :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, [b])]
classes = fmap ((,) <$> fst . head <*> fmap snd)
        . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
        . sortBy (compare `on` fst)

average :: [Integer] -> Rational
average xs = sum xs % genericLength xs

averages :: Ord a => [(a, Integer)] -> [(a, Rational)]
averages = fmap (fmap average) . classes
```

In `classes` you need to sort the list first because `groupBy` only groups *adjacent* values together.